# Count the amount of lua_getfield

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

Is there any way to count the amount of lua_getfield that exists in my code? If yes how?

I have a code with multiple lua_getfield as an example below:

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "MAC");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "IP");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "PASSWORD");
```

I want to create a message to show the amount of lua_getfield being made reading the code in my C program, for example:

```
printf("There are %d lua_getfield", function);
```

Comment: You asked this question the other day didn't you? You got some comments and suggestions in the comments. What happened to that question?

Comment: Yesterday was poorly explained, then deleted.

Comment: I'm fairly certain your question yesterday was **identical** to this one (though I can't check obviously). Deleting and starting a new question also loses any value the comments on the previous question provided (and there was some).

Answer (score 0):

> count the amount

The amount of *what*?

The number of call sites in your source code? Use `grep` or a static analysis tool.

The number of *calls* at runtime? Add a counter to the function or use a profiling tool.

Comment: I have a very extensive lua code, I want to count how many lua_getfield functions exist, and put in a message

Comment: @MarcosSilva You want to count how many times the string `lua_getfield` appears in the source code? Use `grep`. If you mean something else then **add those details** to the question.

Comment: That, plus I want to notify it in a message, and the grep will be possible only I see, what I want and when my program starts it show a message. for example: `There are %d lua_getfield in file test.c`